# How to use ngx-countdown-timer for time h:m:s only?

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular7, angular8

How can i use `ngx-countdown-timer` for time `h:m:s` only?

```html
<div *ngFor="let i of dummy">
    <h1 style="margin-left: 17%; color:#df3b3b">
        <countdown-timer [end]="i.times"></countdown-timer>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the author of `ngx-countdown-timer` doesn't provide much docs so I went through his source code. The author doesn't seem to have an output format either. Perhaps you can raise an issue with the [Github Repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-countdown-timer) itself.

Other than that, you might need to write code to grab the innerHTML of `countdown-timer` every second and convert the string to the format that you want.